# Automating help desk tasks using a Powershell web interface

Tags: iis, powershell, remote-access

I'm looking into implementing Powershell in a help desk environment to automate routine tasks like unlocking user accounts, resetting passwords, etc.

The help desk will be supporting different customer sites remotely from a location that does not have a direct WAN connection to the customer sites.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to implement a solution like that?
 are there any open source/low cost products already available? i know Powershell scripts are available all over the internet but i'm looking for a product that provides the web interface and remote connectivity to the customer sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that [Active Directory Web Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908(WS.10).aspx) will help you do what you want. There is functionality to integrate PowerShell scripts and to use the [Active Directory Administrative Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560631(WS.10).aspx) via this interface.

Answer (score 2):

You need a VPN that connects your techs to the customer sites, this has nothing to do with PowerShell. Or rather, until you have connectivity (probably via VPN), you can write all the .ps scripts you want, they won't do a darned thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Poshboard](http://Poshboard.com) might work for you.  I loaded it up, but haven't done much with it yet.